# Extra unwanted levels using seqdef

Tags: r

When I apply the seqdef function from the TraMineR package to a list of vector and then take a look at the levels obtained, I get two unwanted levels. I can't figure out how to erase those levels. Here is my code:

```
> require(TraMineR)
> seqW <- lapply(X = myListOfVectors, FUN = function(s){
  seqdef(s, alphabet = 1:9)
})
```

After verification, there is only numbers from 1 to 9 in my sequences, but then I get

```
> levels(s$T1)
 [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "*" "%"
```

Where do these "*" and "%" come from ? How can I avoid their creation ?

Comment: I'm using seqHMM and the function comes from the TraMineR

Comment: Try `seqdef(s, alphabet = 1:9,void=NA,nr=NA)`. Read `?seqdef` and the description of the `void` and `nr` arguments.

Comment: It works, thanks ! I should have searched for the link between */% and seqdef, my bad.